# django template -TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, django-templates, backend

I am a beginner in Django world. When I try render my login.html template I'm facing this problem even there is a closing block.

TemplateSyntaxError at /login/
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Here is my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %} 
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div style="margin-top: 30px">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {% if error %}
    <p style="color: red">{{error}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>

{% else %}

<p>
  You're already logged in. Would you like to <a href="/logout/"> logout?</a>
</p>
{% endif %} 

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: `{% csrf_token %}` → `{{ csrf_token }}`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be from the csrf_token. You are using it as a tag instead of variable.

Change `{% csrf_token %}` to `{{ csrf_token }}` and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Actually changing  {% csrf_token %} to {{ csrf_token }} did not affect the situation at all, however, I could solve the problem by myself. I disabled the Prettier extension and render the template again and it worked !!!!! I did not think the extension would be a barrier to running my code.